# WCF List Parameters

Tags: vb.net, wcf, class, list, service

I'm trying to pass a list of objects to my WCF service, but it doesn't seem I can pass an object list from my console test application. I have an error that states:

> Value of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of
>   ConsoleTestingApp.ServiceReference1.LetterVariables)'
>   cannot be converted to '1-dimensional
>   array of
>   ConsoleTestingApp.ServiceReference1.LetterVariables'.

On this line:

```
Console.WriteLine(client.GetLetterObj("1", "1", "0", lstVariables))
```

Anybody have any ideas what I need to do?

Thanks,
Jason

'***************** Code ***********************

My test console app looks like this:

```
    Dim Variables As LetterVariables
    Dim lstVariables As New List(Of LetterVariables)

    Variables = New LetterVariables
    Variables._Sort = 10
    Variables._key = "Letter Number"
    Variables._value = "10"
    lstVariables.Add(Variables)

    Variables = New LetterVariables
    Variables._Sort = 20
    Variables._key = "Amount"
    Variables._value = "$200"
    lstVariables.Add(Variables)



    Console.WriteLine(client.GetLetterObj("1", "1", "0", lstVariables))

    Console.WriteLine("Finished")
```

Here's the contract:

```
<OperationContract()> _
Function GetLetterVariablesObj(ByVal LetterSpecID As Int32) As List(Of LetterVariables)
```

Here's the svc:

```
Public Function GetLetterObj(ByVal LetterID As String, ByVal StateID As String, ByVal CompID As String, ByVal lstVars As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of LetterVariables)) As String Implements ILetterWriter.GetLetterObj
    Dim SQLcon As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Dim SQLcmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Dim Variables As LetterVariables
    Dim tblVars As DataTable


    'Load the datatable to be passed to SQL Server
    tblVars = New DataTable
    tblVars.TableName = "LetterVariables"
    tblVars.Columns.Add("Order")
    tblVars.Columns.Add("Key")
    tblVars.Columns.Add("Value")
    For Each Variables In lstVars
        tblVars.Rows.Add(Variables.Sort, Variables.Key, Variables.Value)
    Next


    'Connect to the database
    SQLcon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=MySRVR;Initial Catalog=Sears;User ID=me;Password=mypass;"
    SQLcon.Open()


    'Set the procedure name, type & connection
    SQLcmd.CommandText = "sp_cmd"
    SQLcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    SQLcmd.Connection = SQLcon


    'Pass the parameters
    SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LetterID", LetterID)
    SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StateID", StateID)
    SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompID", CompID)
    SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Vars", tblVars)


    'Initialize the function string, execute the stored procedure
    GetLetterObj = ""
    GetLetterObj = SQLcmd.ExecuteScalar


    'Close it all down
    SQLcon.Close()
    SQLcon.Dispose()
    SQLcmd.Dispose()
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Collections are exposed as arrays by default. You should be able to pass in `lstVariables.ToArray()`. See [this post](http://www.request-response.com/blog/PermaLink,guid,ff5fab81-affb-4b2b-aa67-c80bdfc86cbd.aspx) for the explanation as to why it is the way it is.

[image]